# Error in using np.NaN is vectorize functions

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization

I am using Python 3 on 64bit Win1o. I had issues with the following simple function:

```
def skudiscounT(t):
    s = t.find("ITEMADJ")
    if s >= 0:
        t = t[s + 8:]
        if t.find("-") == 2:
            return t
    else:
        return np.nan # if change to "" it will work fine!
```

I tried to use this function in np.Vectorize and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/lz09/Desktop/P3/SODetails_Clean_V1.py", line 45, in <module>
SO["SKUDiscount"] = np.vectorize(skudiscounT)(SO['Description'])
 File "C:\PD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2739, in __call__
 return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
File "C:\PD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2818, in _vectorize_call
res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '23-126-408'
```

When I replace the last line [return np.nan] to [return ''] it worked fine. Anyone know why this is case? Thanks!

Comment: `vectorize` makes a test calculation to determine what kind of array is should return.  Looks like your function returns string sometimes, and float (`nan`) other times.  That can mess it up.  Better make sure the function returns a consistent dtype.  Also look into using the `otypes` parameter.  Read the 2nd paragraph of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `otypes` the dtype of the return array is determined by the first trial result:

```
In [232]: f = np.vectorize(skudiscounT)
In [234]: f(['abc'])
Out[234]: array([ nan])
In [235]: _.dtype
Out[235]: dtype('float64')
```

I'm trying to find an argument that returns a string.  It looks like your function can also return `None`.

From the docs:

> The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling
>   the function with the first element of the input.  This can be avoided
>   by specifying the `otypes` argument.

With `otypes`:

```
In [246]: f = np.vectorize(skudiscounT, otypes=[object])
In [247]: f(['abc', '23-126ITEMADJ408'])
Out[247]: array([nan, None], dtype=object)
In [248]: f = np.vectorize(skudiscounT, otypes=['U10'])
In [249]: f(['abc', '23-126ITEMADJ408'])
Out[249]: 
array(['nan', 'None'],
      dtype='<U4')
```

But for returning a generic `object` dtype, I'd use the slightly faster:

```
In [250]: g = np.frompyfunc(skudiscounT, 1,1)
In [251]: g(['abc', '23-126ITEMADJ408'])
Out[251]: array([nan, None], dtype=object)
```

So what kind of array do you want?  `float` that can hold `np.nan`, `string`? or `object` that can hold 'anything'.

Comment: Thanks @hapulj. I do need object type. After adding otypes=[object] it worked!