# Python type casting cannot be NumPy-vectorized

Tags: python-3.x, casting, integer, nan

As an outcome of some data wrangling, I get an array of floats, some of them are NaNs. I know the valid values of this are integer IDs of some objects. Therefore, I want to have them as integers. Nevertheless, NaNs cannot be cast to `int`, so I attempt to cast to integers the finite values only. Also, if for some strange reason upstream I would get a value that has non-zero decimals, I want to regard it as invalid and also cast it to NaN.

The benchmark logic is implemented as list comprehension, and it works as expected:

```py
>>> [int(val) if float(val).is_integer() else np.nan for val in np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> 
>>> [int(val) if float(val).is_integer() else np.nan for val in np.array([1, 2, 3, 3.55])]
[1, 2, 3, nan]
>>> 
>>> [int(val) if float(val).is_integer() else np.nan for val in np.array([1, np.nan, 3, 3.55])]
[1, nan, 3, nan]
```

Encapsulating the logic of the value casting into a lambda also works as long as the calculation is done via list comprehension:

```py
>>> func = lambda val: int(val) if float(val).is_integer() else np.nan
>>> 
>>> [func(i) for i in np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> 
>>> [func(i) for i in np.array([1, 2, 3, 3.55])]
[1, 2, 3, nan]
>>> 
>>> [func(i) for i in np.array([1, np.nan, 3, 3.55])]
[1, nan, 3, nan]
```

Nevertheless, it appears that this logic cannot be vectorized for some reason:

```py
>>> func = lambda val: int(val) if float(val).is_integer() else np.nan
>>> 
>>> np.vectorize(func)(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> 
>>> np.vectorize(func)(np.array([1, 2, 3, 3.55]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2414, in _vectorize_call
    res = asanyarray(outputs, dtype=otypes[0])
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
>>> 
>>> np.vectorize(func)(np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2414, in _vectorize_call
    res = asanyarray(outputs, dtype=otypes[0])
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I have tried to find an explanation as to why this might be the case, but have been unable to find anything. My first thought was that the content of the lambda is executed on the `val` from left to right and, thus, `int(val)` will be attempted before even checking if `flaot(val).is_integer()`. This matches with the fact that

```py
>>> np.vectorize(lambda val: int(val))(np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2411, in _vectorize_call
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

also crashes. However, this would not explain why `int(3.55)` would crash. Indeed, the behavior for just `int(val)` behaves as expected:

```py
>>> np.vectorize(lambda val: int(val))(np.array([1, 2, 3, 3.55]))
array([1, 2, 3, 3])
```

Moreover, defining the logic as a `def` function (where presumably the `float(val).is_integer()` would be evaluated first), also leads to a exception:

```py
>>> def func2(val):
...     if float(val).is_integer():
...         return int(val)
...     return np.nan
... 
>>> 
>>> np.vectorize(func2)(np.array([1, 2, 3, 3.55]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2414, in _vectorize_call
    res = asanyarray(outputs, dtype=otypes[0])
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
>>> 
>>> np.vectorize(func2)(np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/home/dmg/.local/share/virtualenvs/ganot-SqvSo3bL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2414, in _vectorize_call
    res = asanyarray(outputs, dtype=otypes[0])
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Could someone please explain to me why this `int` casting with fallback cannot be vectorized?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was today in the morning after some coffee more inspired to get to an answer. I have found an answer in this post here on SO:

[Error in using np.NaN is vectorize functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763862/error-in-using-np-nan-is-vectorize-functions)

The problem above lies in the inconsistent return type provided by the to-vectorize lambda function.

`numpy.vectorization` provides a parameter `otypes` for explicitly indicating the output types the vectorized function should be compatible with. If not used, the `otypes` are determined automatically by running `func` with the first input. In my examples above, this was returning an `int`, and so the vectorized function was only set for dealing with `int` returns. When, for later inputs, the `func` logic lead to a `float` return type, the return type incompatibility produced the exception.

Therefore, the problem can be solved by e.g.:

```py
>>> np.vectorize(func, otypes=[object])(np.array([1, 2, 3, 3.55]))
array([1, 2, 3, nan], dtype=object)
>>> 
>>> np.vectorize(func, otypes=[object])(np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan]))
array([1, 2, 3, nan], dtype=object)
```